# getting below exceptions when try to print bitmap from brother printer in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, printing, bitmap

When I try to print bitmap from brother printer QL-710W using net port in android am facing below exceptions, if anyone help me on this issue, it will be grateful

> 07-23 18:11:16.752: E/AndroidRuntime(15071): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load createdata from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.splan.android-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.splan.android-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
>   07-23 18:11:16.752: E/AndroidRuntime(15071): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
>   07-23 18:11:16.752: E/AndroidRuntime(15071): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:553)
>   07-23 18:11:16.752: E/AndroidRuntime(15071): at com.brother.ptouch.sdk.PrinterModel.(PrinterModel.java:30)
>   07-23 18:11:16.752: E/AndroidRuntime(15071): at com.brother.ptouch.sdk.Communication.createPrinterModel(Communication.java:498)
>   07-23 18:11:16.752: E/AndroidRuntime(15071): at com.brother.ptouch.sdk.ComNet$CommunicationThread.run(ComNet.java:593)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and finally found it right here on this site. I'm not sure if you're still looking for the answer but for anyone else looking, this might help!

The Brother Printer SDK comes with a libs folder that contains an armeabi folder which in return contains **2 essential .so files**. If you're running Android Studio (as I am), Gradle won't know how to find these. You can fix this by adding the following lines to your **build.gradle** file:

```
task copyJniLibs(type: Copy) {
    from 'libs/armeabi'
    into 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(copyJniLibs)
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyJniLibs'
```

If you moved your .so files anywhere else just adjust the location on the "from" line. Keep in mind that this answer may change depending if Gradle releases an update.